# Как правильно применить regex?

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
$product = 'product_id-14x60338';
```

Как удалить из нее `'product_id-'`? `14x60338` является ID товара, не понимаю, как правильно это сделать

Comment: Если товар всегда product_id-**x****, то может через  explode() можно?

Answer (score 1):

Вспомнил про `str_replace`.

Правильный вариант: `str_replace('product_id-', "", $product);`

Comment: так же и в preg_replace() будет выглядеть, с той лишь разницей, что надо будет дописать ограничители шаблона: `preg_replace('~product_id-~', '', $product);`